# How to append a child to a list containing more than one item.?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

My xml looks like this :

```
<Database>
<Year name="2015" spent="" saved="">
<Month name="" spent="" saved="">
  <Day date="" name="" spent="" saved="">
    <Entry title="" category="" currency="" cost="" time=""/>
  </Day>
</Month>
</Year>

<Year name="2016" spent="" saved="150">
<Month name="" spent="" saved="">
  <Day date="" name="" spent="" saved="">
    <Entry title="" category="" currency="" cost="" time=""/>
  </Day>
</Month>
```

when I use

```
myXML.Year.appendChild(<Month name="2016" spent="150" saved="152"></Month>);
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: Error #1086: The appendChild method only works on lists     containing one item.
    at XMLList/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::appendChild()
```

Any idea?

Here is what I am trying to do: I am developing an android application that logs and keeps track of daily expenses. So, when a user adds a new entry for the year 2015, I check if that year already exists, If it does I want to go inside the years and see if the Month exists, and if it does too, then I check if the current day already exists. If it does, I add the new entry in the Day list and if it doesn't I create a new  node in the Day list. Same goes for years and months. I am having a hard time figuring this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`appendChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#appendChild()) is an [`XML`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) class's method, and for an [`XMLList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html) to be treated as an `XML` object [it should have one XML element](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e70.html) :

> For an XMLList object that contains exactly one XML element, you can use all properties and methods of the XML class, because an XMLList with one XML element is treated the same as an XML object ...

In your case, `xml.Year` return two elements and that's why you got that error.

So to avoid that, you have to get an `XMLList` object with one element like, for example, selecting only the "Year" where the name is "2016" :

```
xml.Year.(@name == '2016').appendChild(<Month name="2016" spent="150" saved="152"></Month>)
```

Hope that can help.