# Why am i unable to use appendChild to an XMLList in an AIR Android Project?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

English is not my first language so I am sorry if the question isn't clear. The problem is I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Money>
<Loan type="Borrowed"/>
<Loan type="Loaned"/>
</Money>
```

I have created a variable of type XMLList:

```
var borrowedList:XMLList = main.moneyXML.Loan.(@type == "Borrowed");
```

Then I used:

```
borrowedList.appendChild(<BLoan amount="" alert=""/>);
```

But it gives me this error:

```
The appendChild method only works on lists containing one item.
```

I tried changing the above variable to:

```
var borrowedList:XMLList = main.moneyXML.Loan.(@type == "Borrowed").BLoan;
```

Still gives the same error.

I hope that clearly explains the question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define `main.moneyXML`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append a child to a list containing more than one item.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231388/how-to-append-a-child-to-a-list-containing-more-than-one-item)

Comment: I've already answered you about the same point in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33231388/2256820) ...